# SQL - Get array of data ordered by occurrences

Tags: sql, database, arrays

I have a table with this kind of data in one of its column:

```
ANS1228E
ANS4987E
ANS1228E
ANS4987E
ANS1228E
ANS4987E
ANS1228E
ANS4987E
ANS1228E
ANS4987E
ANS1802E
ANS1228E
ANS5258E
ANS1375E
ANS1999E
ANS5258E
ANS1228E
ANS5258E
ANS1375E
```

I would like to take these entries and make an array out it with unique entries ordered by their number of occurrences.

What would be the SQL command to use.

**I want to get this result:**

```
Code            Occurrences
------          ----------
ANS1228E                67
ANS4987E                57
ANS1017E                51
ANS1948E                 8
ANS5258E                 7
ANS1802E                 7
ANS4007E                 3
ANS1375E                 3
ANS1301E                 2
ANS5279E                 2
ANS5280E                 2
ANS1468E                 1
ANS1487E                 1
```

**SOLUTION:** (thanks to Chris B. Behrens)

```
SELECT code, COUNT(code) FROM table GROUP BY code ORDER BY COUNT(code) DESC
```

Comment: a column, sorry. post edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT code, COUNT(Code) FROM TABLE GROUP BY Code ORDER BY COUNT(Code) desc
```

Beyond that, we need to know what platform you're trying to create the array in.

Comment: BTW, this orders by higher counts first.

Answer (score 2):

```
select column_name, count(*)
from table
group by column_name
order by count(*) desc
```

Edit: added sorting order desc

Answer (score 0):

The SQL is simple:

```
select theValue
     , count(*)
  from theTable
 group by theValue
 order by count(*) desc
```

Getting it as an array in your application means you pass the sql and retrieve the rows, most languages support returning this data as an array.

Answer (score 0):

First you need the SQL statement for this to get the list and counts

```
select yourcolumnname, count(*) as numberofoccurences
from yourtable
group by yourcolumnname
order by numberofoccurences desc
```

The next part will greatly depend on what tool you are using, but generally, you would create a query with this SQL, then retrieve the rows and for each row, push the element (value, numberofoccurences) into the array.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a `group by` clause. When grouping by a column, you can compute aggregates, including `COUNT`. You can then order your result set by that count and get what you're after.